# kotlin sort list of stings by startsWith()

Tags: kotlin

Is there any way to sort a list by startsWith(), for example having list of string, doing search and all results that starts with query would be at the top of the list?

one way to do it is:

```
    val filteredList = list.filter { it.startsWith(query, true) } +
        list.filterNot { it.startsWith(query, true) }
```

but not seeing it efficient

Comment: About efficiency: In terms of complexity analysis, partitioning is more efficient (at least in time complexity) than any sorting can ever be. Because partitioning is O(n) whereas every sorting algorithm is at least O(n * log n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sortedBy`, it works on Boolean values, but false values are first:

```kotlin
val list = listOf("nope", "abc", "abcd", "bacon", "abba", "bob", "something")

val sorted = list.sortedBy { it.startsWith("ab", ignoreCase = true) }
println(sorted) // [nope, bacon, bob, something, abc, abcd, abba]
```

If you want true values first, you can use the `!` operator inside `sortedBy`.

Note that if you need this 2 sublists independently as well, you can use `partition` instead of 2 calls to `filter`, so that each item is only tested once:

```kotlin
val list = listOf("nope", "abc", "abcd", "bacon", "abba", "bob", "something")

val (matchingItems, nonMatchingItems) = list.partition { it.startsWith("ab", ignoreCase = true) }

println(matchingItems) // [abc, abcd, abba]
println(nonMatchingItems) // [nope, bacon, bob, something]
```

Comment: you have a great answer